# using Lua from within MetaPost

Tags: luatex, metapost, luamplib

Is it possible to run a Lua function from within `luamplib` environment?
This example with runscript does not work, but shows what I like to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex,luamplib}

\begin{filecontents}[force,noheader]{foo.lua}
function getA()
    return "2cm"
end
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\directlua{kpse.set_program_name("luatex") require "foo.lua" }

\begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
        a := runscript("getA()") ;
        draw fullcircle scaled a ; 
    endfig ;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

up-to-date TL 2023

Comment: Not that it helps you, but maybe someone else could be interested to know of [this context way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNaMV.png) of doing it. Maybe there is something similar for LaTeX.

Comment: yes, ConTeXt is no problem, but I didn't find the definition of the MP code inside ConTeXt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible: you just need a `return` statement in the string you pass to `runscript`, like so:

```
\begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(1);
        a := runscript("return getA()") ;
        draw fullcircle scaled a ; 
    endfig ;
\end{mplibcode}
```

This draws a 2cm circle, as you intended.

Comment: Yes, that works. I didn't found it in the documentations.

Comment: The luamplib documentation is rather brief indeed. See the [minim-mp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minim-mp) manual for a longer discussion on the interaction between metapost and lua (minim-mp is a plain-tex-only metapost processor currently, but will support latex in TL2024).